# To what extent could Huygens' principle still apply to the QFT wave-functional?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, spacetime, path-integral, huygens-principle

According to Feynman, the one-particle non-relativistic wavefunction obeys Huygens' principle in that each *point* acts like a source of a secondary wavelet that propagates (1) along all *spacetime* directions (whereas light in optics is restricted to the light cone, or alternatively, all spatial directions), and (2) with a phase change proportional to action (whereas a light wavelet doesn't change phase if you follow its path in spacetime, or changes by the time of travel if you trace it only in space).

In QFT, the system descriptions, and hence the domain of the wavefunction, become field configurations rather than points.  So the connection to Huygens' principle seems much more distant or abstract, because the simple notion of a point source propagating in all directions has to be replaced by a configuration evolving in all possible ways.

But what do we get if we literally just add up all the configurations multiplied by their complex amplitudes, so as to get a single function of spacetime rather than a functional?  This would be pointless in terms of the probability distribution, but how would it evolve?  Would we recover some version of Huygens' principle that would once again apply on a point-wise, rather than configuration-wise, basis?

Or put the other way around, we might say that Huygens' principle in optics is normally described by decomposing the wave into a delta-function basis.  But is it possible that it applies to some other basis than the delta functions?  Because here's the difficulty as I see it: in that other basis, we would have to be able to meaningfully associate a single phase with each basis element (and these would be non-delta, ie. de-localized, functions!), and we would have to find a simple rule that governs the phase shift as any basis element evolves into any other.  This could no longer be the time of travel, because that notion is only well-defined for a pair of points in space.  And in doing so, would we come up with a version that looks more like the path-integral formulation of QFT?